# Change tab-label on gtk.noteBook

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a gtk.Notebook with some tabs on it. How can i change label on current tab when button clicked?
I make:

```
self.set_tab_label(self.scrolled_window,label)
```

But label change on last tab, but not in current :(

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
self.set_tab_label_text(self.get_nth_page(self.get_current_page()),"LABEL_TEXT")
```